# How do i compare with the rest of the elements in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a leetcode question and I cant quite think of a way to compare the rest of the elements in the array with one another. I figured out for the biggest and smallest numbers but to compare with the rest of them is something I am having trouble with. Below you will find the question and my work with it:

How Many Numbers Are Smaller Than the Current Number?

Given the array nums, for each nums[i] find out how many numbers in the array are smaller than it. That is, for each nums[i] you have to count the number of valid j's such that j != i and nums[j] < nums[i].

Return the answer in an array.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: nums = [8,1,2,2,3]
Output: [4,0,1,1,3]
Explanation: 
For nums[0]=8 there exist four smaller numbers than it (1, 2, 2 and 3). 
For nums[1]=1 does not exist any smaller number than it.
For nums[2]=2 there exist one smaller number than it (1). 
For nums[3]=2 there exist one smaller number than it (1). 
For nums[4]=3 there exist three smaller numbers than it (1, 2 and 2).
```

**My work:**

```
var smallerNumbersThanCurrent = (nums) => {
    const output = []

    const max = nums.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.max(a, b);
    });

    const min = nums.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.min(a, b);
    });


    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] === max){
            output.push(nums.length - 1)
        } else if (nums[i] === min){
            output.push(0)
        }
        else if (nums[i] < max && nums[i] > min){
            //how do i compare with rest of the elements in the array?
        
        } 
       }
    }
```

Comment: `const mapper = arr => arr.map(i => arr.filter(n => n < i).length); console.log(mapper([8,1,2,2,3])); // [4,0,1,1,3]` Maps each array item to the length of the array of all items in the initial array smaller than current item. Probably not a great solution for very large arrays, though, methinks.

Comment: Wow... Completely opposite to what "looked" normal from weighing the computations, the `mapper` (filter based) appears to be a lot faster than the `sorter` (sort + findIndex). [A few tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBp2B.png) with an array of 1k random numbers. Values around `430ms` are sorter runs. Values around `30ms` are mapper/filter runs. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wq0hu6b3/). Mind boggling!

Comment: Just added Barmar's answer to the tests and it averages less than `6ms`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested loop.

```js
nums = [8,1,2,2,3];
answer = [];
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
    if (nums[j] < nums[i]) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  answer.push(count);
  console.log(`For nums[${i}]=${nums[i]} there are ${count} lower numbers`);
}
console.log(`Answer: ${answer}`);
```

It's not necessary to test `i != j` since a number will never be lower than itself.

Comment: Your answer averages `6ms` where filter based solution averages `30ms` and sort + findIndex averages `430ms`. [Incredible](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wq0hu6b3/). Chapeau!

Comment: @tao I'd be interested in your timings on my alternate solution...

Comment: @Nick, just add it up, replace the function name in between `t0` and `t1` and hit Run a few times. It's "open source" :). I'll hit the sack and check it in the morning. Cheers!

Comment: @tao It seems your code only runs the loop once, not sure how to "add it up"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219777/discussion-between-tao-and-nick).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to filter the array on the condition that the value is less than the current one and then count the number of values in the filtered array:

```js
const nums = [8,1,2,2,3];

const smallerNums = nums.map(v => nums.filter(n => n < v).length);

console.log(smallerNums); // [4,0,1,1,3]
```

Alternatively you can do a count in reduce, which should be significantly faster:

```js
const nums = [8, 1, 2, 2, 3];

const smallerNums = nums.map(v => nums.reduce((c, n) => c += (n < v), 0));

console.log(smallerNums); // [4,0,1,1,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way would be to simply sort the array, and then the index of the element will tell you how many are less than it:

```js
const nums = [8,1,2,2,3]
const sorted = [...nums].sort();
const result = nums.map((i) => {
    return sorted.findIndex(s => s === i);
});
console.log(result);
```

This has the added benefit that you don't have to search the entire array for each number.

Comment: At first glance I really liked your solution and thought it's probably faster than the filter (which is what i went for out of habit, I guess). Unfortunately, [sort is incredibly slow](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wq0hu6b3/) and appears the ugliest solution (Barmar's) is by far the most performant).

Comment: @tao it's not as bad as you think, in your fiddle you were sorting the array for each loop in `map` when you only need to sort it once. See my answer; this and the other sorting solution have the highest performance.

Comment: @Nick, you're right. Silly mistake. If I move sort out of the map `sorter` becomes decent, even as low as 10 runs. If I increase the number of runs to 100, sorter comes on top. See updated fiddle.

Comment: @tao yeah, I copied your code into a snippet and made another answer. The two sorting algorithms consistently come out on top.

Comment: @Nick still, you'd expect a modern browser to internally memoize a repetitive and expensive operation like `sort` of an array with many items. Obviously, it doesn't. Almost like `sort` could produce a different result every time it's run on same source or could have side effects. Well, it could, when you provide the sorting function...

Comment: @tao yeah - you'd think so wouldn't you. Perhaps because it's inside a `map` and uses a `[...]` structure it's unable to recognise that the input is a constant...

Answer (score 1):

I'd do like:

```js
function rankZero(array){
  const s = [...array], r = [];
  s.sort((a, b)=>{
    return a - b;
  });
  for(let n of array){
    r.push(s.indexOf(n));
  }
  return r;
}
console.log(rankZero([8, 1, 2, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: This has the best performance of the posted answers (at least on my computer), by about 30-40%. See my benchmarking answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @tao I did performance testing of each solution. On my computer (an Intel Core I9-9900 with 64GB RAM) @StackSlave's solution is consistently the fastest, followed by the other sorting solution, the reduce solution, the basic iteration and the filter. You can run the tests yourself below:

```js
const datalength = 1000;
const iterations = 100;

const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const data = Array.from({
  length: datalength
}, () => getRandom(1, 100));

const mapper = arr => arr.map(i => arr.filter(n => n < i).length);

const sorter = nums => {
  const sorted = [...nums].sort();
  const result = nums.map((i) => {
    return sorted.findIndex(s => s === i);
  });
};

const iterator = arr => {
  const answer = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] < arr[i]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    answer.push(count);
  }
  return answer;
};

const rankZero = array => {
  const s = [...array],
    r = [];
  s.sort((a, b) => {
    return a - b;
  });
  for (let n of array) {
    r.push(s.indexOf(n));
  }
  return r;
}

const reducer = arr => arr.map(v => arr.reduce((c, n) => c += (n < v), 0));

let fns = {
  'iterator': iterator,
  'mapper': mapper,
  'sorter': sorter,
  'reducer': reducer,
  'rankZero': rankZero
}

for (let [name, fn] of Object.entries(fns)) {
  let total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    let t0 = performance.now();
    fn(data);
    let t1 = performance.now();
    total += t1 - t0;
  }
  console.log(name, (total / iterations).toFixed(2));
}
```